# Why can't i access enum method through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, associations

I'm kinda new to RoR and i'm stuck with a silly problem (i think). I have two models - Product and order. Order belongs_to product and Product has_one order.

In my order model i have the following enum:  `enum situation: { in_progress: 0, finished: 10 }`

In my controller i have (i get a collection of products registered by the user logged in)

```
@user = current_user
@products = @user.products
```

Then, in my view, i'm interactin through @products and i want to check the state if the order of the specific product:

```
> <% @products.each do |product| %>
>     <% if product.order.in_progress? %>
>        do x
>     <% else %>
>        do y
>     <% end %> 
> <% end %>
```

But i keep getting:

> undefined method `in_progress?' for nil:NilClass

I can't access the order through the product association?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @spickermann. Even when i use has_one association?

Comment: @hawkrox when you use has_one assoaciation, you should use singulative.Most of questions can find answer from ROR guide.https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When t line `product.order.in_progress?` raises an `undefined method 'in_progress?' for nil:NilClass` then that means the `product.order` must return `nil`. You have at least one `product` in your database that doesn't have an order yet and you need to handle that in your view.

I would start with something like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% if product.order.blank? %>
     # no order yet
  <% elsif product.order.in_progress? %>
     do x
  <% else %>
     do y
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Btw does `product has_one order` really make sense, can each product can only be brought once?